# HTML5 QRCodeScanner for attendance system

Tags: javascript, qr-code

I want to youse [HTML5QR Code Scanner](https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode) library in one of my projects.
First I want to say sorry for asking those very basic questions, but I am new to coding in JavaScript, I normally write in PHP.

I'd like to use this library for my school as attendance system.
My idea is: every student owns a qr code
The teacher scans the code with his mobile device. After collecting all codes, the decoded values (name of each student) are written into a database.
I have two problems with that:

**1: Can I collect a list of all decoded values?**
My idea is that scanning, collecting and than writing the values into the database is much faster than doing this process for every student individually.

**2. How can I pass those values to PHP, which I use to write the values into my database?**

Thank you in advance for your help!

Kind regards
Dan

Comment: Looks like an useful library. I think it would be easiest to send the scanned codes one by one to a PHP page, to store it in the database, using [AJAX](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_and_ajax.htm). If you have any problems, implementing that, you can ask a question about that here. Include the code you're using and the problem(s) you have with it. But first, you have got to dive in and try it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If i caught you well i would suggest you to use the following library https://github.com/cozmo/jsQR then implement a very simple interface to allow lecturers (Non-Tech persones) to easily scan the student card and get directly a feedback as the attendance has been taken.

To enhance Fexibility, avoid saving all students details on the the QR datas but instead just save his unique identifier i.e Roll Number and then as soon as his attendance is taken, retrieve all other infomation from database.
For fasten the process, You will need to send the request using Asynchronous Request,check on https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http_send.asp to know more about it.

Finally, Avoid complicated UI on the record page for lecturer, this will avoid misunderstanding.

I've previously worked on attendance system feel free to ask me any other question.